# How to check items in a plist file - cocoa?

Tags: string, cocoa, plist

I've looked at a bunch of other questions and they're not exactly what I need. I'm trying to set a NSTextField to a certain string based on the name of the file. I want to create a plist file with all the possible names of the file and their keys to set the NSTextField's string as. But I don't know how to have it check the plist for the items and if it's not there I want it to execute the code to leave the text field blank. Before I had if statements saying that if the filename equals this then make it say this but I couldn't get the else part to work and only one if worked. So I thought I'd have it check the plist but I don't know how to do that and use it with an if-else statement. This is what I had before:

```
NSString *inputName = [input stringValue];
NSString *theFileName = [[inputName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

if ([theFileName isEqualToString:@"038-3698-001"]) {
    [key setStringValue:@"7ed37d8c051da8f8d31b0ccf0980fa5ffa54770c7e68ecb5ebf28abe683cadf21a4a99ed"];
}

if ([theFileName isEqualToString:@"038-3763-001"]) {
    [key setStringValue:@"a31ffd506c6711c5a0c52c9f0a2f7208a2f63ad9dd40506e70d80ea20a981eb1312bc774"];
}
else {
    [key setStringValue:@""];
}
```

EDIT:
I have it checking the plist for the key but now I need it to get the value for the key from the plist. Something like this:

```
NSString *inputName = [input stringValue];
NSString *theFileName = [[inputName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSDictionary *fileKeys = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Keys" ofType:@"plist"]];

if ([fileKeys valueForKey:theFileName]) {
    NSString *key = [NSString valueForKey:theFileName];
    [filesField setStringValue:key];
}
else {
    [filesField setStringValue:@""];
}
```

Nevermind I got it. This is correct code:

```
NSString *inputName = [input stringValue];
NSString *theFileName = [[inputName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSDictionary *fileKeys = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Keys" ofType:@"plist"]];

if ([fileKeys valueForKey:theFileName]) {
    NSString *key = [fileKeys valueForKey:theFileName];
    [filesField setStringValue:key];
}
else {
    [filesField setStringValue:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can load the plist into a dictionary with something like this:

```
NSDictionary* fileKeys = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
         [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileKeys" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Then you can query for a key with `-valueForKey:`. So, you could check for the filename in the dictionary, and if it is present, set `key` to the associated value.

Comment: this half worked, I can't get the other half. I have it check the plist if the key is there but now, if it is, I need to get the value of the key typed in the textfield